# Optimization on a self-join to a self-reference column

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join, self-reference

I'm trying to join two tables, for example purposes I'll call the first table 'fund', and the second table 'company'.

The fund table, holds information about a fund which relates to a sub-set of companies. The fund table however, only stores the id of a single company (the parent):

[image: fund table]

The company table consists of rows of information about companies, including an identifier from an external system which I need to search on. Companies can be related to another company, through a self-reference column, which through a rule-set allows for only a single level of hierarchy.

[image: company table]

The request for information from the database will always come in with an externalkey, this can belong to a subsidairy (child) or parent company entity. The goal is to find all children and the parent entity related to the company, alongside a join to the fund table for additional information.

Due to the high amounts of requests, this needs to be optimized. Currently I'm running the following query, which works but seems costly due to the multiple OR filters:

```
SELECT * FROM fund
    JOIN company AS csearch ON (csearch.companycompositekey = fund.companycompositekey OR csearch.parentcompositekey = fund.companycompositekey)
    JOIN company ON (company.companycompositekey = fund.companycompositekey OR company.parentcompositekey = fund.companycompositekey)
WHERE csearch.externalkey = '997'
```

My SQL skills are atrocious so I'm wondering am I looking at this completely wrong? Will a 'WITH RECURSIVE (...select for the parent) JOIN fund JOIN children' be a better approach? Something else?

Is it also possible to optimize the filter on 'externalkey' (which is always unique) by calling a LIMIT 1 on the JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `OR` with a `UNION` of all possible combinations:

```
SELECT * FROM fund
   JOIN company AS csearch ON csearch.companycompositekey = fund.companycompositekey 
   JOIN company ON company.companycompositekey = fund.companycompositekey
WHERE csearch.externalkey = '997'
UNION
SELECT * FROM fund
   JOIN company AS csearch ON csearch.companycompositekey = fund.companycompositekey
   JOIN company ON company.parentcompositekey = fund.companycompositekey
WHERE csearch.externalkey = '997'
UNION
SELECT * FROM fund
   JOIN company AS csearch ON csearch.parentcompositekey = fund.companycompositekey
   JOIN company ON company.companycompositekey = fund.companycompositekey
WHERE csearch.externalkey = '997'
UNION
SELECT * FROM fund
   JOIN company AS csearch ON csearch.parentcompositekey = fund.companycompositekey
   JOIN company ON company.parentcompositekey = fund.companycompositekey
WHERE csearch.externalkey = '997';
```

That will run four queries, but they can use indexes efficiently, and you'll probably end up being faster if you have indexes on the join conditions.